# What does it mean for something to be true but not provable in peano arithmetic?

Tags: logic, incompleteness

Specifically, the [Paris-Harrington theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem).

In what sense is it true? True in Peano arithmetic but not provable in Peano arithmetic, or true in some other sense?

Comment: Next time, you should wait a couple of hours before accepting *any* answer...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Peano Arithmetic is a particular *proof system* for reasoning about the natural numbers. As such it does not make sense to speak about something being "true in PA" -- there is only "provable in PA", "disprovable in PA", and "independent of PA".

When we speak of "truth" it must be with respect to some particular *model*. In the case of arithmetic statements, the model we always speak about unless something else is explicitly specified is *the actual (Platonic) natural numbers*. Virtually all mathematicians expect these numbers to "exist" (in whichever philosophical sense you prefer mathematical objects to exist in) independently of any formal system for reasoning about them, and the great majority expect all statements about them to have objective (but not necessarily knowable) truth values.

We're very sure that everything that is "provable in PA" is also "true about the natural numbers", but the converse does not hold: There exist sentences that are "true about the actual natural numbers" but not "provable in PA". This was famously proved by Gödel -- actually he gave a (formalizable, with a few additional technical assumptions) proof that a particular sentence was neither "provable in PA" nor "disprovable in PA", and a convincing (but not strictly formalizable) argument that this sentence is true about the actual natural numbers.

Paris-Harrington shows that another particular sentence is of this kind: not provable in PA, yet true about the actual natural numbers.

Comment: You might mention that, regardless of how convincing is the argument that the Gödel sentence $G$ is true, the proof that it is not disprovable in PA also shows that $\lnot G$ is not provable in PA, and so one of $G$ and $\lnot G$ must be true but not provable. So it is possible to be convinced that there a sentence tha tis true but not provable in PA, without being convinced that $G$ is true.

Comment: It should be noted that the statement which Paris-harrington proves undecidable (unprovable, yet true in some models) was, the first *non-synthetic* statement for which this was shown. The statements which Gödels proved unprovable are very synthetic, and unlikely to occur as actual number-theoretic questions. The strengthened Ramsey theorem that Paris-Harrington proved undecidable, OTOH, is argueable of some pratical interest *apart* from the fact that it's undecidable in PA.

Comment: Also there could be "provable and disprovable in PA"?

Comment: @hjg: that would mean that PA is inconsistent. PA is widely believed to be consistent, and it can also be proven consistent on the basis of various weak assumptions (see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentzen's_consistency_proof ), but of course those assumptions might _themselves_ be inconsistent.... Certain ultrafinitists might not believe that PA is consistent.

Comment: @Henning: this question is related to your answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/590378/630

Answer (score 16):

The Paris-Harrington theorem is actually the theorem that states that the strengthened [finite] Ramsey theorem is unprovable in first-order Peano Arithmetic.

However, since the Ramsey theorem is provable in second-order arithmetic, and therefore true in the standard model of Peano arithmetic, we can say that the theorem is *true* in a very deep and concrete sense.

Generally speaking, when we say a statement about the integer is true we mean that it is true in *the* standard model, which is the model of second-order Peano arithmetic, and it is all the numbers which can be generated by finitely many iteration of the successor function from zero. (Non-standard models of first-order PA exist, and there are non-standard integers which cannot be generated by finite iterations of the successor from zero.)

You may also want to read [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69353/true-vs-provable) about the difference between truth and provability.

Comment: So if something is provable in second-order arithmetic, then it is true in Peano arithmetic?

Comment: @fhyve It is then true in the *standard model* of peano arithmetic (if it's expression in first-order language, that is). It is not true in peano arithmetic in general (which is a set of axioms, *not* a particular model), i.e. there *are* models of peano arithmetic where it's false.

Comment: @fhyve: The second-order theory of Peano arithmetic has *exactly* one model up-to isomorphism (unlike the first-order theory which has many non-isomorphic countable models). This model is known as the *standard model of PA*, and it is [trivially] a model for first-order PA. The strengthened finite Ramsey theorem can be stated in first-order PA, but cannot be proven using it. It can be proved using second-order so it is true in the model of second-order PA, which means it is true in the standard model of first-order PA as well.

Comment: So I am confusing formal theory with model when I say "something is true in peano arithmetic"?

Comment: @fhyve: Yes; see my answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Re: your second paragraph. (I did not want to ask a separate question.) For statements independent of $\text{ZFC}$, is there a common choice of a theory that is stronger than $\text{ZFC}$ which maybe decides some more statements? I am wondering what the 'next step up' could be. And would there be any sense (I speak informally here) in describing a formula that is independent of $\text{ZFC}$ as 'true', if it is satisfied here? Thanks

Comment: @Szmagpie: I'm not sure what you mean. There are extensions of ZFC, e.g. V=L, which decide a lot of things like CH and the likes of it; and there is the large cardinals hierarchy for statements stronger in the sense of consistency.

Comment: @AsafKaragila If theorems (such as PH) are true in the standard model, then we say they are 'true', even if independent of $\text{PA}$; I was wondering what an analogous convention could be for theorems independent of $\text{ZFC}$—perhaps this could be an extension to $\text{ZFC}$—or whether this is not possible and I have gotten confused somewhere!

Comment: @Szmagpie: No, there is no canonical model for ZFC that we can say something is true but not provable.

Comment: Working in ZFC if a statement is undecidable in internally defined ZFC can it be true in the external ZFC? If so, how is that possible, won’t we have a contradiction by repeating the proof of undecidability in the externally defined ZFC? Like we could let the statement be RH since it is often said that if RH is undecidable in ZFC then it is true.

Comment: @VivaanDaga: In any reasonable form of this, and certainly in any way I can think of, internal versions of logic and of ZFC are always including their meta theoretic counterparts. So proofs you can write in the meta-universe can be written internally.

Comment: Right, so it’s impossible for ZFC to prove that RH is independent of internal ZFC because then it would be true in external ZFC, a contradiction. Then why do people say that if RH is undecidable in ZFC then it must be true? The universe it must be “true” in can’t be ZFC can it? Is the universe something like ZFC+CON(ZFC) or even stronger?

Answer (score 16):

The other answers are excellent, but I would like to point out that Peano arithmetic is a particularly bad first example for understanding the distinction between truth and provability because

- you have an intuitive notion of what the word "true" means that is getting in the way, and
- there are, roughly speaking, two levels of mathematics going on and it is easy to confuse them.

So let's pick a better example where there's no possibility of confusion: the [first-order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) theory of [groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_theory). I'm not going to spell out in detail what this is; consider it an exercise to write it down in full. After writing down the language of groups, write down the group theory axioms.

"Provable" has an unambiguous meaning here: it means "provable from the axioms of group theory." By the [completeness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem), this is equivalent to "true for all groups."

"True" is meaningless here unless you take it to mean "true for all groups," which is not the sense in which the Paris-Harrington theorem is true. What is meaningful is to say that a statement in the language of groups is true in a particular model: for example, the statement

$$\exists g : g \neq e, g^2 = e$$

is true in a group $G$ precisely when that group has a nontrivial element of order $2$.

The difference between group theory and first-order Peano arithmetic is that when it comes to Peano arithmetic, mathematicians have a special model that they really like, namely the "actual natural numbers," and "true" in this context means "true of this special model." As Asaf says, one way to define this model is as the unique model of second-order Peano arithmetic; however, first-order Peano arithmetic does *not* have a unique model (e.g. by [upward Löwenheim-Skolem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem)).

This is very different from the situation with group theory; nobody has a group $G$ that they like so much that they would define "true" to mean "true of $G$"!

As a final remark, note that by the completeness theorem, "true of the actual natural numbers but not provable" is equivalent to "true of the actual natural numbers but false for [some other model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic) of Peano arithmetic." This may seem like a strange state of affairs, but the analogous situation in group theory ("true of some group but false of some other group") is not so strange.

Comment: That last sentence was especially helpful in light of the other comments. Thanks

Comment: Actually PA is a *good* example, once you understand what is a model of a theory. This is because there is exactly one model of second-order PA means that we can treat that as *the* standard model of first-order PA, and define a statement as "true" if it is true in that model.

Comment: @Asaf: but my point is precisely that PA is a bad example if you _don't_ understand what a model of a theory is and are trying to learn. Nonstandard models of Peano arithmetic look like this bizarre thing instead of a general feature of first-order logic, and thinking about other first-order theories first seems to me to be a much better way of coming to terms with this idea.

Comment: I do agree that for understanding the difference between semantic and syntax, and so on, models of PA are messy. Yes, group theory makes a much nicer example (or my preferred example: field theory and the number of roots for $x^3-2$). However I strongly agree with Carl in the comments to fgp's answer. When talking about PA, we have a concrete meaning when we say that a statement is "true".

Answer (score 12):

You seem to be confused about the meaning of *true* when it comes to peano arithmetic. Peano arithmetic usually refers to a particular set of axions about the natural numbers, formalized in first-order predicate logic.

If you have a statement $A$ and a set of axioms $T$ it can be that

1. $A$ is provable in $T$. $A$ is then true in every model of $T$ (A model is a particular implementation of a set of axioms if you will - it assigns actual values to all constant symbols which occur in the axioms, actual functions to all functions which occur in the axioms, and so on).
2. $A$ is true in every model of $T$. In first-order predicate logic this implies that $A$ is provable in $T$. (Note that this is *not* the case in second-order predicate logic!). Some people might abbreviate this as "$A$ is true in $T$", but that may be missunderstood as "$A$ is true in the standard model of $T$", so this abbreviation should be avoided.
3. $A$ is true in a *particular* model of $T$. This implies nothing about the truth of $A$ in other models, and nothing about whether $A$ is provable. It does imply, however, that the *opposite* of $A$ cannot be profable, otherwise that particular model would have to satisfy $A$ *and* its opposite.
4. $A$ contradicts $T$. This is the same as $T$ proving the opposite of $A$, and obivously no model can then fulfill $A$, since all fulfill the opposite of $A$.

In the case of PA, people might also say "True over the integers" or simply "true" instead of "True over the standard model of PA". Especially because PA is not the only axiomatization of the integers.

The generalized Ramsey theorem (sometimes called *Paris-Harrington Principle*, btw) is *not* provable in PA, but it is *true* in the *stanard model* of PA, i.e. in the usual integers. We know that because it is *provable* in second-order arithmetic, i.e. a second-order axiomatization of the integers.

Comment: So it is kind of like how if you say something is true about a field, then it is true about the field of real numbers? And as an analogy in this case, a field is like peano arithmetic and the field of real numbers is like a model in that it is a specific instantiation of a field?

Comment: @fhyve Yes, exactly!

Comment: You are somewhat missing the point, though. Since PA has a standard model, we can say that something is true if it holds in the standard model.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But we wouldn't say "True over PA" if we mean "True in the standard model of PA". Or at least I'd find that quite confusing. The point I was trying to make was precisly that people sometimes *do* say "True over PA" when the actually mean "Provable over PA" or equivalently "True over *all models* of PA" and *not* "True over the standard integers". And, while that may be a bit confusing, it's not wrong - Gödel's completeness theorem guarantees that.

Comment: No, and that's the point. If we say that a statement about the integers is true, we mean that it is true in the standard model. If we wish to discern we say that it is consistently true in a *non-standard* model.

Comment: @fgp: that is correct in a sense, but also we don't usually say "true over PA"; that is not a phrase I would use. The question does say "true in PA" but that is a sign that the asker has not yet figured out how to ask the question correctly. When they read "true but not provable in PA" they appear to mistakenly think this means "true in PA but not provable in PA" when it really means "true in $\mathbb{N}$ but not provable in PA".

Comment: Right, I justed wanted to give a sensible interpretation of "True in PA". Especially because I've heard that phrase before, even in lectures. And in my experience, people generally meant "Provable in PA", not "True in the standard model of PA". "True over the integers" or variations thereof are a different question - if there's no explicit reference to a set of axioms *then* it undoubtedly means "true over the standard model". Still, I'll fix the answers to explain that saying "True over PA" is confusing, and should be avoided.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ok, hope people take less issue with this now...

Comment: It should be noted, not every theory has a standard model; and that the Paris-Harrington theorem is simply the proof of the unprovability of the Ramsey theorem.

Comment: @fgp: i have voted +1 on the edited version which is very clear to me

Answer (score 0):

Note that (according to Wikipedia) the proof of the Paris-Harrington theorem goes by assuming it is true in Peano arithmetic and showing this can prove Peano is consistent (within Peano).

Because Gödel has shown this is not possible, it must not be possible to prove the theorem in Peano.

So as far as understanding it, you can fall back on Gödel: he showed there are statements in a formal theory that cannot be proved (or disproved) by that theory but are true in a formal theory with more axioms. This is one of those statements for Peano.