# Theorem of the Continuum Hypothesis in ZFC

Tags: logic

There is a theorem that neither CH nor ~CH is provable in ZFC. Since it is a theorem is must have been proved. Is the proof possible within ZFC itself or do you need formal systems more powerful than ZFC to show it for ZFC?

Comment: The theorem needs the assumption that ZF is consistent, because an inconsistent theory proves everything. But except for that, much less than ZFC is needed; Peano arithmetic is more than enough.

Comment: You need the assumption that ZFC is consistent (since otherwise it proves everything), which (by the incompleteness theorem) is not provable in ZFC itself (unless it is inconsistent).

Comment: So under the assumption that ZFC is consistent the theorem could be proved in ZFC itself, right?

Comment: See the related [Why is CH true if it cannot be proved?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494099/why-is-ch-true-if-it-cannot-be-proved)

Comment: @Pippen No, if ZFC could prove ZFC can’t prove something, it would prove ZFC is consistent, violating Godel (unless ZFC is inconsistent). On the other hand, ZFC +Con(ZFC) will prove it.

Comment: ZFC proves [If Con(ZFC), then CH is independent from ZFC]. Equivalently: ZFC+Con(ZFC) proved [CH is independent from ZFC]. (Here, Con(ZFC) is the assertion that ZFC is consistent)

Comment: I suppose another way to phrase that is, ZFC proves that either neither CH nor ~CH have proofs in ZFC, _or both do_.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: Is not your „ZFC + (Con)ZFC will prove it“ and my „under the assumption of ZFC‘s consistency the theorem can be proved in ZFC“ the same?

Comment: @Pippen There's a big difference between "ZFC+Con(ZFC) will prove it" and "If Con(ZFC) is true, then ZFC will prove it"! If Con(ZFC) is true, then ZFC will _not_ prove it. Gödel's second theorem says if Con(ZFC) is true, then ZFC will not prove Con(ZFC).

Comment: @Pippen "Any reasonable metatheory + Con(ZFC)"  proves "CH is independent of ZFC". But "any reasonable metatheory + Con(ZFC)" *disproves* "ZFC proves CH is independent of ZFC".  (With, e.g, ZFC+Con(ZFC), ZFC, or PA  being reasonable metatheories.) So "the assumption of Con(ZFC)" does not imply "the theorem can be proved in ZFC itself" (unless our metatheory is inconsistent with Con(ZFC)). Whereas "ZFC + Con(ZFC)" does prove "the theorem" (where "the theorem" = CH is independent of ZFC ).